# Calling a method within a dynamic method in VB.NET

Tags: .net, reflection, dynamic, reflection.emit, opcode

So for the past hour I have been trying to use a Dynamic Method in VB.NET to call a sub inside the calling class.

I've had no luck with a couple of things. Firstly, while trying to follow the example from MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228971.aspx) I wasn't able to make the method a Sub and not return anything at all since I just want to call another method.

eg.

```
Private Sub FirstMethod()

    Dim methodArgs As Type() = {}
    Dim MyNewMethod As New DynamicMethod("MyNewMethod", Nothing, methodArgs, GetType(Crux).Module)
    Dim il As ILGenerator = MyNewMethod.GetILGenerator()
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, OtherMethod)
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret)
End Sub

Private Sub OtherMethod()
    MsgBox("This is some other method!")
End Sub
```

The thing is, I don't want it to return anything and I just want it to call OtherMethod() and I would like a way to call the Dynamic Method in my code (through a delegate). MSDN hasn't really helped at all, and I cannot find anything that even tries to explain a way to do what I want.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try using linq expressions and compiling them into a delegate. 
It's easier than the old fashion reflection.emit.

```
  class Demo {
    public void Foo() {
        var instance = new Demo();
        var method = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(instance), instance.GetType().GetMethod("Bar"));
        var del = Expression.Lambda(method).Compile();
        del.DynamicInvoke();
    }

    public void Bar() {
        Console.WriteLine("Bar");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `DynamicMethod` is not really about dynamically calling a method, it's about dynamically *building* a method, as in constructing a complete method body at runtime.

If you want to call a method, you could simply use the `Invoke` method on the `MethodInfo` you already have. Which, for a void method without arguments is simply

```
var type = this.GetType();
var method = type.GetMethod("OtherMethod");
...
method.Invoke(this, null); // call this.OtherMethod()
```

Now, if you want to encapsulate that in a `Delegate`, you'd use

```
var action = (Action) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action), this, "OtherMethod");

action(); // call this.OtherMethod()
```

I've chosen Action as the type of delegate here, but you can use any compatible delegate type.

There are several overloads of `Delegate.CreateDelegate` that can help you here, including overloads which take a `MethodInfo`, so you can use reflection to get the right method info, and the call `CreateDelegate` to make a delegate of the type you want.

---

Mind you, if the method you want to call is known at compile time, you can skip the whole reflection thing, and let the compiler do the work for you:

```
Action action = this.OtherMethod; // using a so-called method group
Action action = () => this.OtherMethod(); // using a lambda
Action action = delegate { this.OtherMethod(); } // using an anonymous method
```